# option:last-of-type / option:last-child not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have this input field:

```
<select name="billing_address_id" id="billing-address-select" class="address-
select" title="" onchange="billing.newAddress(!this.value)">
<option value="1">Option1</option>
<option value="2">Option2</option>
<option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

I always want to hide / get rid off the last option. This is what I figured out working in Chrome but unfortunately not in Safari:

```
select#billing-address-select option:last-of-type {display: none;}
```

Any chance to get this working across all browsers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't `display: none` on  elements in Safari. Safari (and IE) is restricting CSS on form elements.

**EDIT**

But you could use some javascript to rebuilt your select :

```js
var $select = $('#billing-address-select option').detach();

$('#billing-address-select').empty().append( $select.filter('.add') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="billing_address_id" id="billing-address-select" class="address-
select" title="">
  <option class="add" value="1">Option1</option>
  <option class="add" value="2">Option2</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>Option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: last-child is also not working unfortunately (see thread title).